# Random Number From Normal Distributions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, normal-distribution

Is `randn()` in Matlab actually using an inverse normal distribution to generate the random numbers from normal distributions?

Comment: Did you forget to share the code that you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

[This manual page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randstream.html) says:

> NormalTransform:  Transformation algorithm used by randn(s, ...) to
>   generate normal pseudorandom values. Possible values are 'Ziggurat',
>   'Polar', or 'Inversion'.

You specifically asked about inversion, so I'm assuming you're already familiar with it.  Here are links in case you want to know more about the [Ziggurat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm) or [polar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method) methods.

Comment: To answer the OP's question, you might add that the Ziggurat method is the default method used, not inversion.

Comment: It used to be specifically indicated in `doc RandStream`. It's still mentioned in `help RandStream`. And you can also call `RandStream.getGlobalStream`.

Comment: @horchler Thanks for the info.  I'm not surprised that Ziggurat is the default, since it's pretty widely considered the most efficient.